# Eclipse quit Unexpectedly on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, macos-catalina

I have just installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers on Mac OS Catalina Version 10.15.7, yesterday. I dragged the Eclipse.app from the Downloads folder to the Application folder. It was working just fine. I created a couple of servlets. But today when I clicked on the app to open it, I got a problem report (Error), and so it didn't open.

The error details are..

> Time Awake Since Boot: 3300 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid) Exception
> Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1
>
> kernel messages:
>
> ### VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
>
> ```
> __TEXT                 000000000c447000-000000000c44b000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW
> ```
>
> Thread 0 Crashed: 0   ???
> 0x0000000015674000 _dyld_start + 0
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
> 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000
> rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi:
> 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffee37bcc60
> r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10:
> 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000   r12: 0x0000000000000000
> r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15:
> 0x0000000000000000   rip: 0x0000000015674000  rfl: 0x0000000000000200
> cr2: 0x0000000000000000    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
> 0x00000000 Trap Number:     0

---

In fact, I already googled the issue but the solutions that worked for others didn't work for me. For example, I tried the following solutions:

- move the Eclipse.app from the Application folder
- `eclipse -clean`
- I double clicked the executable eclipse, which in  `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`

I thought of re-installing Eclipse, but before that I want to know if there is a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Code Signature Invalid* means that the app has somehow been corrupted which causes the signature to not match anymore. Re-installing is the proper course of action to fix this.

As for what caused it, it's something that happened between the last successful launch and the first time it didn't start. Maybe it's a bug in Eclipse itself, maybe it's an action you took. It's hard to figure out after the fact. If it keeps happening, the [Eclipse bugtracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) is the proper place to report it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said, I will just re-install it.

Answer (score 6):

Modern Eclipse (2021-09 and perhaps even before) has a major incompatibility with **Gatekeeper** which checks for CODESIGNING of the Eclipse.app bundle. *Self-modification* of bundles is not permitted by Apple as it undermines the security model of macOS -- as malware protection (Xprotect). See: https://eclecticlight.co/tag/gatekeeper/

I suspect the Info.plist changes after initial launch or when modifying some user preferences or IDE settings.

Workaround such as trying to codesign manually is cumbersome and didn't work for me on Catalina:

```
codesign -v -vvv --deep /Applications/Eclipse.app
/Applications/Eclipse.app: invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)
In architecture: x86_64

sudo codesign --force --sign -  /Applications/Eclipse.app
Password:
/Applications/Eclipse.app: replacing existing signature
/Applications/Eclipse.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/${user.home}
```

What did work for me was defining an exception for Gatekeeper's Xprotect by recursive removal specific extended attribute for quarantine. Use the following directly after installing Eclipse and before running it:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

See: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/17/what-to-do-when-you-cant-launch-an-app/